# ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias , alias are present (inner query with group and having)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I need to select countries where unofficial lang-s twice more than official,+ officials are 2+

MYSQL Query:

```
SELECT c2.countrycode , sum(c2.isOfficial) as isFalse
FROM countrylanguage as c2
 INNER JOIN (
        select c.countrycode , sum(c.isOfficial)as isOffTrue 
        from countrylanguage as c 
        where c.isOfficial='T' 
        group by c.countrycode 
        having sum(c.isOfficial)>1)
         ) as cisT 
 ON cisT.countrycode = c2.countrycode 
  where c2.isOfficial='F' 
  group by c2.countrycode 
  having sum(c2.isOfficial)>cisT.isOffTrue*2
```

But I getting alias error, and can't define the root cause of the problem, 
could you pelase help me ?

LATER....

RC:  extra ) in join

NExt Error: does not recognize internal sum() alias, could you pelase help ?

```
  SELECT c2.countrycode , sum(c2.isOfficial) as isFalse
FROM countrylanguage as c2
 INNER JOIN (
        select c.countrycode , sum(c.isOfficial) isOffTrue 
        from countrylanguage as c 
        where c.isOfficial='T' 
        group by c.countrycode 
        having sum(c.isOfficial)>1
         ) as cisT 
 ON cisT.countrycode = c2.countrycode 
  where c2.isOfficial='F' 
  group by c2.countrycode 
  having sum(c2.isOfficial)>(cisT.isOffTrue*2);
```

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cisT.isOffTrue' in 'having clause'

Addition:

Table:

```
 +-------------+---------------+------+-----+--------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
| CountryCode | char(3)       | NO   | PRI |         |
| Language    | char(30)      | NO   | PRI |         |
| IsOfficial  | enum('T','F') | NO   |     | F       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+
```

I changed query like next one and it worked, buy I still do not get the RC of previous failure

```
SELECT c2.countrycode, sum(c2.isOfficial) as isOffFalse, c1.isOffTrue 
  FROM (
select c0.countrycode, sum(c0.isOfficial)as isOffTrue 
from countrylanguage c0 
where c0.isOfficial='T' 
group by c0.countrycode having sum(isOfficial)>1
) as c1, countrylanguage as c2
  where c1.countrycode = c2.countrycode 
and c2.isOfficial='F' 
group by c2.countrycode 
having sum(c2.isOfficial)>(c1.isOffTrue*2);
```

Comment: This code would not seem to be generating that error.  You have other problems with the code, but not that one.  You should include sample data, desired results, and a clear statement of the problem in your questions.

Comment: One off the errors @GordonLinoff is talking about is misusing MySQL GROUP BY feature..  https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Some errors:  `sum()` on a character constant, misuse of `group by`, selecting the wrong columns in the outer `select`, unbalanced parens.  Actually, now that I look closer, the last of those is generating your specific error.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I found the problem  -- have an extra )

now there is a next issue -  in does not see internal sum() alias 

could you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are joining

ON cisT.countrycode = c2.countrycode

but countrycode column does not exist in cisT table.

Comment: Foun the RC of first issue, 
but have the next exception